# Which stack exchange site is for printer hardware mechanical design papers?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to understand how printer pickup roller and paper feed roller works. With equations and the detailed physics behind it. I have searched on the google about white papers but I couldn't find any.

Could you please tell me which stack-exchange that I should ask this question? Which stackexchange I could find people who design printers, such as people who working for epson , HP and their engineering design core ?

Comment: Your title is a different question than your body.

Comment: @RobertHarvey What title you prefer? Please feel free to edit it.

Comment: I didn't find a Stack Exchange site that fits your question (assuming that it is a real question, and not just a "call for papers"), so I proposed a new one.  Feel free to follow it here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44908/mechanical-engineering?referrer=LtuR7WrBOcaU41zfK7oIpw2

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Good move! I was just thinking there should be an ME proposal.

Comment: yes @RobertHarvey ,this is a real question , but more than a asking for papers question, This for me where to start question.I seriously don't know where to find details.
Give me some time to calibrate the question I'll ask that at area61

Answer (score 4):

After rereading your edited question title, it seems like you're looking for links to external documentation.

This is likely to be considered a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), meaning that you're asking people to recommend other resources for you.  The best Super User questions would be about a specific problem that you are having with personal computers or personal hardware. In short, the audience targets everyday people who are trying to solve computer problems via a "do it yourself" mentality.

While my suggestion to join the [Super User Chat Room](https://superuser.com/) still stands, questions asking for links to external documents aren't really what Stack Exchange is about.

Comment: I'm asking for a white paper, not either a shopping catalog.

Comment: I understand, but asking for lists of things is not what Stack Exchange is really about. Your questions should treat our communities as the experts, not merely librarians who can point you to the right reference material. For further reading, see [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Good luck! :)

Comment: I have already look for documents on google. 
But I didn't found it. That way not seems to be working.
So I have to design from scratch. yes I have do it myself mentality now, I need some time to calibrate this question now.

Such as how much damping should I use? What kind of pressure down leaver that I could use. And my new idea, I need to add a paper alignment mechanism using a differential amplifier. etc etc.

Comment: I think I need to calibrate the question.

Comment: Again, if your question is specific to solving a problem you're having where the community gets to share their expertise, then you'd have a better chance. Join that chat room, if you haven't. Those folks can not only tell you if your question is on-topic, but they may even be able to help you tailor your question to make it fit. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

"With equations and the detailed physics behind it" At this point we go beyond practically answerable, to deep theory.

'Which stackexchange I could find people who design printers, such as people who working for epson , HP and their engineering design core ?' It's rather unlikely that a whole bunch of industry experts just happen to be in a SE.

I think the issue here is scope. You're essentially asking something that is probably something that initially was found out by a bunch of boffins in a shed. Then a lab. For all we know there are entire rooms of folks working on the perfect printer feeder.

The moment you need *white papers* to begin to answer your question, it's gone past Q&A into thesis territory. It's just not a good fit anywhere.